# Solution of Helmholtz equation in three dimensional

Tags: complex-analysis, partial-differential-equations, distribution-theory

Let $k$ be a complex number such that 
$$im \;k>0$$

the function

$$u(x,y):=\frac{1}{4\pi} \frac{e^{ik|x-y|}}{|x-y|}, x,y\in \mathbb{R^3}, x\neq y$$

is a solution of the Helmholtz equation

what i tried is :

the equation $\nabla^2 u(\vec x)+k^2u(\vec x)=0$

reduced to $\nabla^2 u+k^2 u=\frac1{r^2}\frac{\partial }{\partial r}\left(r^2\frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right)+k^2u=0$ by using spherical symmetry

which can be $\frac{\partial^2}{\partial r^2}(r u)+k^2 (ru)=0 $

then $ru=C_1 \cos(kr)+C_2 \sin (kr)$ from here how to processed

thank you so much

Comment: Are you trying to derive the solution yourself or validate that it is an actual solution?

Comment: @mattos.. deriving solution